# Store the database table to array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Please someone help me. I have problem like this:

I want to get data from database and store it in array. Example:

my product table:

id::name::price::qty

1::Red Shoes::10::2

2::Black Dress::20::3

3::Blue Skirt::30::1

I want get data from that table an store in array like this:

```
    $items = [
        array(
           'id' => '1',
           'price' => 10,
           'quantity' => 2,
           'name' => 'Red Shoes'
        ),
        array(
           'id'=> '2',
           'price' => 20,
           'quantity' => 3,
           'name' => 'Black Dress'
        ),
        array(
           'id'=> '3',
           'price' => 30,
           'quantity' => 1,
           'name' => 'Blue Skirt'
           )
    ];
```

I try using this code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product");
$data_item = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $data_item['id'] = $row['id'];
    $data_item['price'] = $row['price'];
    $data_item['quantity'] = $row['qty'];
    $data_item['name'] = $row['name'];

}

$items = [$data_item];

print_r($items);
```

This is the output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [price] => 30 [quantity] => 1 [name] => Blue Skirt ) )
```

With that code I just get the last data and 2 others not store inside array. Why this happen?

How to get output like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [price] => 10 [quantity] => 2 [name] => Red Shoes ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [price] => 20 [quantity] => 3 [name] => Black Dress ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [price] => 30 [quantity] => 1 [name] => Blue Skirt )  )
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems - you are only grabbing a single array that way. 1) `$items` needs to be inside the `while` loop in order to grab each `$row` and 2) `$items` needs to be a multidimensional array (i.e. an array of `$data_item`s).

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $data_item['id'] = $row['id'];
    $data_item['price'] = $row['price'];
    $data_item['quantity'] = $row['qty'];
    $data_item['name'] = $row['name'];

    $items[] = $data_item;

}
```

From there, you can iterate through the `$items` array to see all of your items. If you do a `print_r($items)`, you should see the output you expect.

Also, for the record, you could simplify by using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()` - using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` will bring along the key (field) values as well. Then you could simplify the building of `$items` down to a single line of code (which is commonly done):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) $items[] = $row;
```

This should give you the same result as your initial attempt when you `print_r($items)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as it is written right now, is overwriting portions of that $data_item array for each iteration in the while loop.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $data_item[]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $data_item[]['price'] = $row['price'];
    $data_item[]['quantity'] = $row['qty'];
    $data_item[]['name'] = $row['name'];

}
```

This should fix your problem and as a side note you may want to look into mysqli or PDO database connection handlers since mysql is on the way out and deprecated with php versions 5.5+ (http://www.php.net//manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) Additionally, the mysqli result class has a nice fetch_all method to grab all the results from a query to avoid having to iterate over rows.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
$data_array = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Granted with this syntax you are limited to using the database column names as your array keys but it does take significantly less code to accomplish nearly the same thing.